# problems after paperclip adding a image to controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I've got a problem updating the params of a model after adding a picture to the model.

Model is user, I've added a image to the user model with paperclip.

When I upload a picture with paperclip it is stored correctly in filesystem and in Database, but after that I can't change any other param of the user.

Thats the method how I update the attributes

```
  def settings
   @usergroups = User.find(session[:user_id]).user_groups
   if request.post?
     if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
    end
   end
 end
```

Thats the method for uploading the image

```
  def uploadimage
    if request.post?
     @user = User.find(params[:userid])
     if @user.update_attribute(:image, params[:upload][:image])
       flash[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
       redirect_to :action => :settings
    end
  end
end
```

If the picture is stored in db it looks like this in user table:
[image]

Model has this:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:id/:filename",
                :url => "/uploads/:id/:filename"
```

**UPDATE**

```
  validates_attachment :image, :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" }
```

Picture upload form and other attributes form are two different forms.

Does someone have an Idea whats going wrong?

problem comes from:

```
validates_attachment :image, :content_type => { :content_type => "image/jpg" }
```

**is there a possibility to only validate if :image attribute is changed?**

Comment: Are you getting an error? 

To answer your question, what you can do is add an if check on your validate. `if: :image_changed?`

Comment: How should it look like? If I add it i got image_changed? is not a function